# Jquery empty() but do not empty the first two objects when emptying

Tags: jquery

This is how my div structure looks like:

```
<div id="firstDiv">
   <div class="itemName"></div>
   <div class="exitContainer"></div>
   <div id="secondDiv">
       <div class="itemName"></div>
       <div class="exitContainer"></div>   
  </div>
   <div id="thirdDiv">
       <div class="itemName"></div>
       <div class="exitContainer"></div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to delete everything except for:

```
<div id="firstDiv">
   <div class="itemName"></div>
   <div class="exitContainer"></div>
```

Is empty() the best way to go or is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) ...

Comment: `$("#secondDiv").remove(); $("#thirdDiv").remove();` will remove the unwanted `div`

Comment: @KarelG I have 30 of these firstDiv, secondDiv, thirdDiv etc... And in my program I dont know the name of them, I only know the name of the first one. So i need to collapse everything below the first element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#firstDiv > div:not(.itemName):not(.exitContainer)').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstDiv">
   <div class="itemName">1</div>
   <div class="exitContainer">2</div>
   <div id="secondDiv">
       <div class="itemName">3</div>
       <div class="exitContainer">4</div>   
  </div>
   <div id="thirdDiv">
       <div class="itemName">5</div>
       <div class="exitContainer">6</div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

This will delete everything except you add to ":not()"